# How to display shortest route between multiple destinations in UWP Map Control

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I am following this
[tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/routes-and-directions).
It shows how to display route between TWO points on map.

Is there a way to display shortest route between more points on map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in an array of waypoints rather than just the start and end waypoints: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn636949.aspx

Note that the route it calculates is the shortest route going through that array of waypoints, in the order they are defined in the array. This map API does not provide travelling salesmen  routing which reorders the waypoints.